# Expose a persistent DataSet that includes Change Tracking

Tags: c#, wcf, datatable, dataset

I want to expose a WCF service operation that sends *new* records in a database. Each time the operation is invoked, it should return a DataSet object that includes only rows that have been added to the database since the last time the operation was invoked.

My question is whether this is possible by serializing the DataSet between calls and then using GetChanges() and AcceptChanges() methods.

Ie (pseudocode),

```
 [OperationContract]
 public DataSet GetDataSet() 
 {     
       DataSet ds = LoadDataSet();   // load a dataset from saved xml or binary

       DataSet newDs = GetRecordsFromDatabase(); // load dataset from database

       ds.Merge(newDs, true);  // somehow recognize which records in the newDs 
                               // load are new?
       return ds.GetChanges(); 
 }
```

Comment: If you can identify the user requesting the dataset. You could store the amount of records in the dataset, for each user. You could then select all the records that were added after, using the count. This'll only work when the dataset is ordered.

Comment: Yep I am doing something like this, using a LIFO stack that stores the latest entry for each entity / database view. Was just wondering if this sort of persistent data set concept is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
```

My suggestion:
Do not serialize datasets. Maybe you can preserve the ID of the last record you inserted.

Regards,
M.